# How can I stop the laptop from beeping?

Tags: laptop, windows-11, lenovo-laptop, beep-code

Every time I boot my laptop (Lenovo Ideapad 3 15ALC6), it beeps 4 times (two times in quick succession, it then waits about a second and then beeps another two times in quick succession) but still boots up successfully. In fact, I am using it to write this question.

I bought this laptop less than three months ago. It was working fine up until today. It is running Windows 11.

Comment: “I bought this laptop less than three months ago.” Was this a new machine when you purchased it? Used? Seller “refurbished?”

Comment: See https://technick.net/guides/hardware/beep_codes/ for POST codes. If you bought it 3 months ago, it's still not too late to wipe and return... but why wait 3 months to ask? From your question, "**Every** time I boot my laptop (Lenovo Ideapad 3 15ALC6), it beeps," it seems this has been a problem from day 1.

Comment: I'm not in the country where I bought it .

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  Before that happens, I pressed the novo button while the pc was running and it beeped. Can it be the actual cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the laptop is still under warranty, I suggest that you ask for it to
be replaced or at least to be fixed.

I understand that the beeps form the pattern of 2-2-2.
According to the
[Troubleshooting POST/startup does not complete issues - Servers](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht105741-troubleshooting-poststartup-does-not-complete-issues-servers),
this pattern may mean "Keyboard controller failed" on the
System Board.
You should also examine the screen while the beeps are issued,
to see if any messages are issued (if the messages disappear
too fast to read, film the screen with your phone during the boot).

The error might be different from my above interpretation, but it's sure
that the problem is hardware.
Try to disconnect any possible device and boot.
If nothing changes, call Lenovo Support for this problem - it's not
something you can analyze or fix.

Comment: No message on the screen and keyboard works fine. How do I contact Lenovo  Support?

Comment: One starting point is [Lenovo Technical Support](https://support.lenovo.com/), but your vendor might be a better starting point.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, probably it happens when BIOS updating.

I did battery reset, holding power button for 20-40seconds, and problem is gone...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did fix it some weeks ago by updating the computer using both Lenovo Vantage software and windows update.